# how to get 1 month of report in databse to listbox c#

Tags: c#

so first of all i have a calender and a checkbox, how do i get a 1 month of report from databse when i checked on the checkbox and display it to the listbox what is the sql command for that or is there any better code to do it ?

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();s
            string year = DateTime.Now;

            string FirstDayofMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from reservation where Date ='" + date + )
        }
```

Comment: this is what im able to do till now

Comment: Please use execute reader and then bind data to list box.